# Reinforce a Simultanious Rate Limit for Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a tasks queue object in the real-time database, and all across the day, tasks are being created (1 every 5 minutes or so).

I have a cloud function listener that onCreate takes the task, processes it, and deletes it. Which takes ~30 seconds and works fine.

Every day at midnight I create around 10,000 tasks (which will only increase in the future). Each task needs to connect to a third party server, and to an SQL database. This causes one of two types of errors:

1. Third party server has a simultaneous connection limit so it kicks me out.
2. The database can't handle the many many connections and throws a "Too many connections error"

Is there a way to limit the maximum cloud functions workers for a single function? I would like to set the limit to ~10, so I won't get any of those errors.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to limit the concurrency of Cloud Functions at the moment. If you want to control this, you'll instead have to limit how many tasks you create at a time.

I've run into this problem with legacy back-end systems myself too, so would definitely recommend that you also [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: I implemented a sub-queue of 50 max tasks, that when the main-queue is created or the sub-queue depletes takes 50 new tasks to run. This is better than nothing but might need to revisit in the future.